# Why am I getting an "element not interactable" error when trying to select a search bar using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

total beginner here trying to learn Python using Automate The Boring Stuff.

As practice, I am trying to create a program that will search a website for a given food item, and identify if a specific ingredient is contained in that food item's ingredients.  The website I am using to search is https://world.openfoodfacts.org/.

What I would like to do is take input from the user and then input that into the website's search bar.  I am able to identify the search bar element using selenium, however when I try to input it, I get the following error:

```
  File "C:/Users/black/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/harambes revenge.py", line 37, in <module>
    searchbar.send_keys('%s' % product)
  File "C:\Users\black\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 477, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
  File "C:\Users\black\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\black\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\black\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.97)
```

My current theory is that this has something to do with the search bar on the website changing position depending on if the window is maximized.  Unfortunately I don't know much about HTML or CSS (but am learning a lot just by troubleshooting this!)

Here is my code, thank you for taking a look and please let me know if you have any ideas!

```
product = pyip.inputStr('What product do we want to take a look at?')

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://world.openfoodfacts.org/')
browser.implicitly_wait(5) #a google search told me to try this, no effect
try:
    searchbar = browser.find_element_by_name('search_terms')
    print('found element %s' % searchbar) #able to find element
except:
    print('could not find element')

searchbar.send_keys('%s' % product)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element is outside the visible page. One quick way to deal with this is to do maximize window.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.maximize_window()
# rest of your code
```

You can do the same thing by setting it as an option on instantiating Chrome:

```
options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('start-maximized')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
# rest of your code
```

A 3rd way is to use [`ActionChains.move_to_element`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.move_to_element) and bring the webelement into focus.